# How can I get a list of supported date formats in PHP programatically?

Tags: php

In much the same way as `DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers()` lists out all the timezones supported by PHP, is there a way to get it to output a list of all the date format identifiers?

The list of formats is available on this page for reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php However, I can't seem to find an internal function that returns this as an array. If you look at example #4 on that page, you'll find that they've manually built an array with formats and descriptions:

```
$strftimeFormats = array(
    'A' => 'A full textual representation of the day',
    'B' => 'Full month name, based on the locale',
    'C' => 'Two digit representation of the century (year divided by 100, truncated to an integer)',
    'D' => 'Same as "%m/%d/%y"',
    'E' => '',
    ...
```

Is there really no way to get this list automatically?

*Update:* My specific use case is in templating. I'm providing a templating "language" within my app and I want to use, among other custom tags, standard PHP date format identifiers so the users may format the date the way they want. My app will receive the template with tags such as `%d%`, `%y%` and so on and it will return the values for that.

I am opposed to opinion that this is unnecessary, because the same argument can be made against having a function that makes PHP return the list of timezone names. Why not simply have a script that makes it's own co-relation between timezone offsets and timezone names and use that? Why make the compiler/interpreter return this information?

I don't even agree with the argument that this is an edge case as there are innumerable applications which directly base their templating date formats based on PHP's official format identifier list, for eg. MailChimp.

Comment: You can use that script written by a user with your same requirements. Why not?

Comment: No there isn't a way, because there is no real need for it

Comment: What @MarkBaker said. It's trivial to just make an array like you started doing, just put the right info in there and you're good.

Comment: Can you describe a single use case in which this would be useful in practice? If so I would be happy to consider implementing this in PHP. Just go to https://bugs.php.net submit it as a feature request and note the bug report number in here and I will assign it to myself. If you can prove that there's a real need for it I'm not opposed to implementing it.

Comment: @Sherif I have thought of this. I'll append my use case in the question above.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude I could use a script (or write my own), but if the list of formats change with any version, I'll have to update them.

Comment: @aalaap why is it necessary to extract the format specifiers for your templating engine to work? Simply passing along the format string should work just fine. Almost any modern templating engine in PHP allows you to use PHP code anyway since it's already a great templating engine on its own. I don't see a strong enough use case here.

Comment: @Sherif The template contains tags other than PHP's date tags, so I need to go through each of them, check them against the variable tags in my database (non-date) and then in the next step, check if they're PHP date tags, replace them and move to the next.

Comment: Difference between a list of timezones, and a list of date format codes: date format codes require a change to actual PHP core source code to implement a new mask, or to change the behaviour of a mask; but new timezones can be added/changed completely independently of PHP via the external tz database, and PHP simply provides methods to access this list and base date information on the data held in that database

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in function to do this, so a function like this will have to do:

```
function getDateFormatIdentifiers() {
    return str_split('dDjlNSwzWFmMntLoYyaABgGhHisueIOPTZcrU');
}
```